# mod_rewrite generating errors in log

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, logging

On my site I have mod_rewrite rules to make the URLs more search engine friendly, and it all works fine on the frontend, but I'm getting errors in the error log like this

```
[Thu Jan 22 22:51:36 2009] [error] [client {IP ADDRESS HERE}] File does not exist: /{some rewritten directory}
```

The rules I'm using are rather simple, along the lines of

```
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)_(.*).html$ page.php?id=$2
```

Is there a way to avoid these errors?

Comment: Which is the path given in the error? Is it /page.php or something else?

Comment: The path is the directory most of the time (/pages/) though occasionally a file within that directory (/pages/image.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) could cause this. If it is enabled, Apache tries to find a file similar to the requested URI before passing the request along to mod_rewrite.  So try to disable it:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think those errors have anything to do with mod_rewrite, they're just saying that a file doesn't exist.  Plain old 404 errors.

Incidentally, shouldn't rewrite patterns normally start with a slash? Like so:

```
RewriteRule ^/pages/(.*)_(.*).html$ /page.php?id=$2
```